# prestashop 1.6 working with bootstrap plugin - Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, prestashop

I'm using the default theme that is based on bootstrap, I'm trying to open a simple modal popup box.

Using the example in http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp, i.e. I created a module that transplant this code in the hookDisplayTop using a tpl

But the modal CSS was completely messed up, so I figure I should use the bootstrap CSS, so I added to hookHeader the following code:

```
    $this->context->controller->addCSS ( "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css", 'all' );
```

The css is still a mess but I can fix it easily.

I'm bewildered since I expected a bootstrap based theme to have modal out of the box (especially since prestashop uses many popups).

also, if just include the css it might override other css that i'm not aware of.

so I guess i'm missing something basic on how to integrate bootstrap plugins into prestashop.

My question is: what is the correct way to add a bootstrap plugin (e.g. Modal) to a prestashop default theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you can see in this file

[themes/default-bootstrap/sass/_bootstrap.scss](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/themes/default-bootstrap/sass/_bootstrap.scss)

some components (modal included) have been disabled in default theme.
This was indeed very poor decision when making this theme.

However, including Bootstrap again (like you did) is even worse. You're practically duplicating CSS code.

If you must keep working on your current theme, then include only the missing parts:

[bootstrap.css#L5869-L5991](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L5869-L5991)

[bootstrap.css#L6492-L6498](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L6492-L6498)

[bootstrap.css#L6513-L6516](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.6/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L6513-L6516)

Make a custom `.css` files and copy this code, the include it using the same method.

I can also suggest a simple PrestaShop theme that has update Bootstrap and all of its components: [PrestaShop/community-theme-16](https://github.com/PrestaShop/community-theme-16). It it a work in progress and there may be bugs, but it's definitely a better starting point for making a new theme

Comment: If I want to add plugin in the future, how do I find the relevant css lines to copy?

Comment: Go to http://getbootstrap.com/components/ to get the idea what classes the component uses, but it's usually prefixed very well, like `.modal-*`, so it's easy to find. Just use `ctrl+f` to find these classes in the link I have in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. Helped me lot.